# I cant seem to run this Quartz code I made. Its supposed to print Hello every 2 minutes

Tags: java, spring, maven, quartz

I made this code using gpt, it's a maven project. Here is the code -

App.java -

```
package com.example;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
//I am not sure what do do with this file
```

PracticeApplication.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;


public class PracticeApplication extends QuartzJobBean 
{
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

QuartzSchedularConfig.java

```
package com.example;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class QuartzSchedulerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobDetail job1; // Autowire the job bean
    @Autowired
    private SimpleTrigger trigger1; // Autowire the trigger bean

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("quartz-config.xml"));
        scheduler.setAutoStartup(true);
        scheduler.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);

        // Use the autowired job and trigger
        scheduler.setJobDetails(job1);
        scheduler.setTriggers(trigger1);

        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

quartz-config.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="job1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.example.PracticeApplication" />
        <property name="durability" value="true" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="trigger1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="job1" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="120000" /> <!-- Repeat every 2 minutes -->
        <property name="repeatCount" value="0" /> <!-- Repeat indefinitely -->
    </bean>`


</beans>
```

It only runs the App.java file and then code stops.

Its supposed to print Hello every 2 mins.

Now I cant use anything else except for QuartzBeanJob and  because thats how the codebase for the actual application is set up.

Comment: You can see how spring entry point looks like in their [quickstart guide](https://spring.io/quickstart).

Comment: @Chaosfire Thats for spring boot. I need for spring, the codebase doesnt use springboot.

Comment: Can you try with -1 in the <property name="repeatCount" value="0" /> or with 10 just to try?